# How to convert to time in millis from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS date in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig, jodatime, piggybak

I have one date chararray 2014-11-02 16:57:29. i want to convert this into long how can i do this?

I tried from the link 
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/ISOToUnix.html

```
DEFINE ISOToUnix org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix();

DEFINE CustomFormatToISO org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.CustomFormatToISO();

ISOin = LOAD '/user/sample/test.csv' USING PigStorage() AS (dt:chararray, dt2:chararray);

toUnix = FOREACH ISOin GENERATE ISOToUnix(CustomFormatToISO(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')) AS event_time;

DUMP toUnix;
```

test.csv contains
2014-11-02 16:57:29 2014-11-02 13:13:05

I am getting

> [POUserFunc (Name:
>   POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix)[long]
>   - scope-5 Operator Key: scope-5) children: null at []]: java.lang.NullPointerException.

Could somebody please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ISOToUnix(CONCAT(REPLACE(dt, ' ', 'T'), '.000Z')) looks a good an quick answer. here we convert the string to iso then using ISOToUnix using valid timezone